# How to fix Message: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using below code for database connection

```
class Database extends PDO{

    function __construct(){

        try {
            parent::__construct(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            Logger::newMessage($e);
            logger::customErrorMsg();
        }

    }
}
```

every thing like login , fetching data was working fine . Now suddenly I am having a exception error message

```
Message: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Code: 1040
```

How to fix this error ?

I have a model class there I am creating new database.

```
 class Model {

protected $_db;

public function __construct(){
    //connect to PDO here.
    $this->_db = new Database();
    }
  }
```

and every model I make , I am extending from model class.

Comment: You are exhausting the maximum permitted connections set by the MySQL server. Are you in control of the database server? Verify also that you are not connecting via `new Database()` to instantiate this class _inside a loop_, as that is a quick way to use up your available connections.

Comment: I have phpMyadmin access . where from I set maximum permitted connections?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html If you are on shared hosting, you likely don't have access to increase the max connections.

Comment: You must be instantiating a lot of models, such as in an array of objects, I would presume.

Comment: yes my hosting is a share hosting. I am running multiple sub domain as different site and multiple database in a single phpmyadmin

Comment: If this is a single application and the user/pass does not change, you may want to use a persistent connection. You get one connection from your application to the database that all your "connections" use. Even if you close the app and reopen it, the connection remains cached for some time so it may be reused.

Comment: what attribute I need to set to make a persistent connection in my above code ?

Comment: @AvijitDas Don't use a persistent connection for this. It isn't necessary, and your problem is not that you need to reuse the old connection across multiple script executions (the purpose of persistence), it is that you are unnecessarily opening too many connections in this single script execution. See my explanation below.

Comment: @AvijitDas In any case, I did add the persistent connection part below. I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because your `Model` class instantiates a new `Database` object in its constructor, each time you instantiate a `Model` (or any class extending it), you are in effect opening a *new* database connection.  If you create several `Model` objects, each then has its own independent database connection, which is uncommon, usually unnecessary, not a good use of resources, but also actively harmful as it has used up all the server's available connections.

For example, looping to create an array of `Model` objects:

```
// If a loop creates an array of Model objects
while ($row = $something->fetch()) {
  $models[] = new Model();
}
// each object in $models has an independent database connection
// the number of connections now in use by MySQL is now == count($models)
```

#### Use dependency injection:

The solution is to use dependency injection and *pass* the `Database` object into the `Model::__construct()` rather than allow it to instantiate its own.

```
class Model {

  protected $_db;

  // Accept Database as a parameter
  public function __construct(Database $db) {
    // Assign the property, do not instantiate a new Database object
    $this->_db = $db;
  }
}
```

To use it then, the controlling code (the code which will instantiate your models) should itself call `new Database()` only once.  That object created by the controlling code must then be passed to the constructors of all models.

```
// Instantiate one Database
$db = new Database();

// Pass it to models
$model = new Model($db);
```

For the use case where you actually need a different independent database connection for a model, you can hand it a different one.  In particular, this is useful *for testing*. You can substitute a test database object, or a mock object.

```
// Instantiate one Database
$db = new Database();
$another_db = new Database();

// Pass it to models
$model = new Model($db);
$another_model = new Model($another_db);
```

#### Persistent connections:

As mentioned in the comments, using a persistent connection is possibly a solution, but *not the solution I would recommend*. PDO will attempt to reuse an existing connection with the same credentials (as all yours will have), but you don't necessarily want the connection to be cached across script execution.  If you did decide to do it this way, you need to pass the attribute to the `Database` constructor.

```
try {
  // Set ATTR_PERSISTENT in the constructor:
  parent::__construct(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
  $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}
```

The relevant documentation is here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#example-950

#### Singleton solution:

Using a singleton pattern (also not recommended), you could at least reduce this to a search/replace in the model code.  The `Database` class needs a static property to keep a connection for itself. Models then call `Database::getInstance()` instead of `new Database()` to retrieve the connection.  You would need to do a search and replace in the Model code to substitute `Database::getInstance()`.

Although it works well and isn't difficult to implement, in your case it would make testing a little more difficult since you would have to replace the entire `Database` class with a testing class of the same name. You can't easily substitute a test class on an instance by instance basis.

Apply singleton pattern to `Database`:

```
class Database extends PDO{
   // Private $connection property, static
   private static $connection;

   // Normally a singleton would necessitate a private constructor
   // but you can't make this private while the PDO 
   // base class exposes it as public
   public function __construct(){
        try {
            parent::__construct(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            Logger::newMessage($e);
            logger::customErrorMsg();
        }

    }

   // public getInstance() returns existing or creates new connection
   public static function getInstance() {
     // Create the connection if not already created
     if (self::$connection == null) {
        self::$connection = new self();
     } 
     // And return a reference to that connection
     return self::$connection;
   }
}
```

Now you would need to change only the `Model` code to use `Database::getInstance()`:

```
class Model {
    
  protected $_db;
    
   public function __construct(){
     // Retrieve the database singleton
     $this->_db = Database::getInstance();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , and it helped me to understand the problem. My application is almost complete ,it will be very dificult to modify each controller and model , is there any quick solution so that I need to modify minimum code to fix this?

Comment: this is a model class User_model extends Model {

 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
 }

Comment: You can _try_ it with persistent connections, but you really should fix the models. It would be possible to substitute a singleton pattern instead of calling `new Database()` in the models, but you would still need to change the code for each class.

Comment: Thank you Michael for this solution . I will try this and let you know.

Comment: In the Class Database extends PDO example, you have set the construct to private, but PDO construct is public.  It produces this error: " Access level to Database::__construct() must be public (as in class PDO) in.."

Comment: @CarlBarrett Oh, nice find. That would be a typical pattern for a custom Singleton, but doesn't work out the same when extending an existing class with a public constructor. It would have to be public, and perhaps include a condition to throw an exception if its caller is from outside the class (to keep the true singleton behavior)