# Should a base PHP database class create multiple connections?

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a data class for handling MySQL queries and then all other classes such as `login`, `products` extend this class to make use of the database. As a result, each page load creates 2 or more DB connections due to something similar to the following:

```
$login, parent::__construct(); // check login via db
$products, parent::__construct(); // fetch products from db
```

Is there a way around this such as adding some code in the constructor to verify whether an existing DB connection has already been established?

A fellow developer I work with writes in procedural style and simply uses a single global `$_db object` for all queries and, this seems a lot more efficient as it only creates 1 DB connection.

Comment: You should use `DI` and pass an instance of your `DB` class to your `Factory` classes. This way U only have one open connection per client

Comment: You could set your `$_db_object` to be static inside your class (`private static $_db_object`), and in the __construct() verify if `self::$_db_object` is connected, if not connect it.

Comment: No, you want your applications to open only a single database connection, multiple connections will create unwanted overhead in the application. @Naomi static is one way to go, but dependency injection is the preferred method, your abstraction should be de-coupled from the connection, and you pass the connection into the model.

Comment: I was just helping out on a question where multiple connections caused a problem (using up all the server's connections) because objects were instantiating their own connections. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26981461/541091

Comment: Thanks, Michael. That's what I was looking for! Never really did understand static classes... Bit off-topic but so from what I've read after a bit of further research, static classes are like a global variable in the sense that when any of its methods are called, they all use the same instance? $db1 = dbi::getDbi(); $db2 = dbi::getDbi(); Then $db1->query(); and $db2->query(); ends up using the same instance, doesn't matter what variable you the static instance is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For many smaller applications, I make my database instance global to the whole application, along with configuration and other application-wide classes, such as logging.  This is not necessarily the preferred method, as it couples code to expect things named certain ways, and could possibly cause conflicts down the road.  However, for small utility applications it is convenient.

For anything larger, I usually utilize my DB from an ORM anyway, so it becomes a non issue.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's example of creating a static class and how to use it helped resolve the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981461/541091